# Proving surjectivity of Hopf map and existence of Hopf Circles on $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am using the Hopf Map $f: \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb{S}^2$ where $f(a,b,c,d) = (2(ab+cd),2(ad-cb),(a^2+c^2)-(b^2+d^2))$

My question is

1.) How can I prove surjectivity of the map? I am aware of the primary definition of surjectivity but I am unsure how to apply in this case.

I tried using the trivial method of finding an inverse but the method is very complicated.

2.) How can I show that a point that the preimage of $q \in \mathbb{S}^2$ is a circle in $\mathbb{S}^3$?

I realize that the solution is dependent on finding the inverse function as hinted in the first part, but since the function itself was complicated to find, hence I had no progress in this part.

Comment: It might be helpful to view the two-sphere and three-sphere in slighty different ways: we can view the two-sphere as $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and the three-sphere as the elements in $\mathbb{C}^2$ of magnitude 1. Then the Hopf map is given by $(z,w) \mapsto [z:w]$.

Comment: @BrianShin How can I demonstrate the equivalence of the two maps?